# The datasource configuration "default" was not found(test CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

**I get an error when testing CakePHP table.**

I didn't seem to be able to solve it myself, so I asked a question.
Thank you.

**[error contents]**

```
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource configuration "default" was not found.
```

**[Where the error is occurring]**

/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/UsersTableTest.php

```
$this->users = $this->getTableLocator()->get('users', $config);
```

※I couldn't even try a different description

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$this->users = $connection->get('users', $config);
//It didn't work even if'default'was'test'
```

**[What is done]**

The following methods work fine in the "/src/Controller/UsersController.php" location, which is not the test location.

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
```

**[What i don't understand]**

I don't understand why something that works fine in other classes doesn't work in the test

**[What went]**

①
"test_aaaa_db" which created a database separately from the one for production use.
②
The above contents are set in "/config/app_local.php".
DEBUG is also true.

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),


    'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'mysql',
            'username' => '***',
            'password' => '***',
            'database' => 'aaaa_db',
        ],
 
        'test' => [
            'host' => 'mysql',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '***',
            'database' => 'test_aaaa_db',
        ],
    ],
```

③
I put the necessary tables in the created database in advance.
I also have some records.

④The fixture file is created as follows.

/tests/Fixture/UsersFixture.php
(There is nothing other than the following description)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

/**
 * UsersFixture
 */
class UsersFixture extends TestFixture
{
    public $import = ['table' => 'users'];    
}
```

⑤I created a file for the table

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Table\usersTable;
// use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
/**
 * App\Model\Table\usersTable Test Case
 */
class usersTableTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test subject
     *
     * @var \App\Model\Table\usersTable
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fixtures = [
        'app.Users'
    ];

    /**
     * setUp method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $config = $this->getTableLocator()->exists('users') ? [] : ['className' => usersTable::class];
        $this->users = $this->getTableLocator()->get('users', $config);
    }
    
    public function testFindAuth(): void
    {
        $query = $this->users->find('auth')->select(['id']);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query', $query);
        $result = $query->enableHydration(false)->toArray();
        $expected = [
            ['id' => 1],
            ['id' => 2],
            ['id' => 3],
            ['id' => 15],
            ['id' => 19]
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }
    
    /**
     * tearDown method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        unset($this->users);

        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

⑥The following files are also included.

The settings around here are a little uneasy.
By the way, I have confirmed that there is no problem by outputting code coverage in html.

/phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/8.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
  
</phpunit>
```

/phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    >
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    </php>

    <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="app">
            <directory>tests/TestCase/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <!-- Add plugin test suites here. -->
    </testsuites>

    <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector">
            <arguments>
                <object class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager"/>
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>

    <!-- Ignore vendor tests in code coverage reports -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">plugins/*/src/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>src/Console/Installer.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**[What I didn't do because I didn't think it was okay]**

- Create Entity for command typing Test below.
  (Actually, I did it, but the error content did not change.)

```
bin/cake bake test Entity user
```

Comment: Compare your custom PHPUnit config (`phpunit.xml`) with the one that shipped with the app template (`phpunit.xml.dist`), it's obviously missing CakePHP related configuration/references.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I would like to review phpunit.xml etc.!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I'm sorry,

At the time of testing, it seemed to fail by referring to "phpunit.xml" where I should have looked at "phpunit.xml.dist".

So I was able to eliminate the error output by not referencing "phpunit.xml.dist" as "aphpunit.xml.dist",

I'm still new to "phpunit" so I'd like to study more in the future.

By the way, if you have "phpunit.xml", you will see "phpunit.xml", if you don't, you will see "phpunit.xml.dist"!

Thanks for the hint, ndm!